# Removing all spaces on $input files

Tags: php, space

Just want to remove the spaces of the input file (or the file selected when I browse the files on my computer).

Specifically, I use the ffmpeg.exe in the web through the ffmpeg-php.. I manage and explore the functions of ffmpeg.exe in the DOS(Disk Operating System) and I notice that ffmpeg.exe can't recognized spaces.. so when I use it in the ffmpeg-php.. input files with spaces on its filename did not do the conversion process and ive got OKB files.. so i need some help on php-scripts where when i browsed files from my drive, input filename ignore the spaces or automatically deleted the spaces of the filename of the input file..

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '', $filecontent);`? If this is the solution you probably didn't look at the manual, but I assume, you just need to clarify the question.

Comment: Please be a little more descriptive. You want to remove all spaces in a text, while you are opening a file?
Like using a str_replace!? http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: To be more specific, I have here my file like for ex. Raw Video.avi , and I browse that video and convert it, but I want to remove the Spaces between raw and video. It must be RawVideo.avi. How can I remove the spaces for every input file.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('foobar.txt');
$content = preg_replace('|\s+|', '', $content);
file_put_contents('foobar.txt');
```

This use [file_get_contents](http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents](http://fr.php.net/file_put_contents) to manipulate files, [preg_replace](http://fr.php.net/preg_replace) to replace spaces. [str_replace](http://fr.php.net/str_replace) would also be able to replace the space if you are confident with your regular expressions.

---

EDIT after the OP explained.

To rename file you have the [rename](http://fr.php.net/rename) function. If you want to make the process on a whole directory you can use [scandir](http://fr.php.net/scandir).

example:

```
foreach (scandir('/tmp') as $file) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    rename('/tmp/' . $file, '/tmp/' . str_replace(' ', '', $file));
}
```

Comment: To be more specific, I have here my file like for ex. Raw Video.avi , and I browse that video and convert it, but I want to remove the Spaces between raw and video. It must be RawVideo.avi. How can I remove the spaces for every input file.

Answer (score 0):

use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('/\s/', '', $input_string);
```

Comment: To be more specific, I have here my file like for ex. Raw Video.avi , and I browse that video and convert it, but I want to remove the Spaces between raw and video. It must be RawVideo.avi. How can I remove the spaces for every input file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make reusable function

```
function replaceFile( $file, $reg, $replacement ) {  

     return file_put_contents(  $file, preg_replace( $reg, $replacement,file_get_contents( $file ) );
} 

replaceFile( "file.txt", /\s+/","");
```

Comment: I'll put the function replaceFile( $file, $reg, $replacement ) {  

     return file_put_contents(  $file, preg_replace( $reg, $replacement,file_get_contents( $file ) );
} 
on javascript
but where can I put 
replaceFile( "file.txt", /\s+/",""); ?

Comment: Question is about how to do it in php so i wrote function in/for php